# How to make camera work with pi 4b 64 bit ubuntu 20.10

Tags: camera, ubuntu

After add start_x=1 in the config.txt

#start_x Enable the camera module.

start_x=1

#disable_camera_led Turn off the red camera LED when recording video or #taking a still picture

disable_camera_led=1

#gpu_mem minimum GPU memory for camera use

gpu_mem=512

After a reboot I can see now a video0 device under /dev
Can see the /dev/r

but zoom or anyother  apps uses web camera c
annot see camera,  or cheese is not working

Change to respbian 64 bit, the camera is not working either

Comment: Please fix the formatting. There are also several errors in your `config.txt`

Comment: I reformatted the machine ,lost config.txt, There wass no eorr in the config.txt, the other line are commented out

Comment: The easiest way to do ANYTHING on a Pi and Ubuntu is **don't use Ubuntu**.
The Server works well enough (if not spectacularly) but is a resource hog. It IS POSSIBLE to install a GUI but this is not endorsed by Canonical.
The only "supported" Desktop image is [Ubuntu Desktop 20.10](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) which requires a 4/8GB Pi4.
There is nothing that can't be done using **Raspberry Pi OS** (which has DOCUMENTATION and support).